# Emulate Numpad prevents Selection Modes from working

Tags: modeling, sculpting, shortcut

I'm working in Blender 2.8 on a laptop, so I enabled "emulate numpad" option in settings.

But in this case, the shortcuts for toggling between selection modes (polygon/edge/vert) don't work anymore (because 1,2,3 keys now work as num1, num2, num3).

Is there a way to overcome this problem?
Or how would you suggest to remap the selection modes?

Comment: You can search by key-binding in the preferences. So you can find what assigned to "1" and modify it to an other key.

Comment: @FFeller Thank you, that's what I did, after all. I use "emulate Numpad" and I reassigned selection mode keys to num1, num2, num3. I was thinking maybe there are some alternative solutions or recommendations, otherwise, the question can be closed, and if you will add this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks ones again!